# Issue with key (cipher error) when changing laravel folder structure

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5, directory

I am changing **laravel 5.3** folder structure. What I exactly do is basically move all the content from `public` folder to root folder, and then all the other files besides `public` folder to the new created folder - `project`. Then I update the require paths in `index.php`, and when I try to run the project via `XAMPP`, I'm getting this error.

[image]

I am pretty sure that the key is set correctly, because I haven't changed anything else but the folder structure and paths, and the project worked before this folder structure change. It seems to me that program can't locate the `.env` file.

Comment: Why ruin the laravel structure? its the best way to use laravel.

Comment: I think there's no wrong in changing the folder structure. If it's a good framework you should be able to. Laravel is indeed a good framework. You have the flexibility to do anything with it. I too have changed its folder structure to my needs couple of time. My focuses are the system requirement and business domain. It governs the architecture of the project. there is no harm in changing stuff as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: I want to upload laravel project on shared hosting using only FTP.

Comment: check how your paths are set in the container.

Comment: Which container do you mean @Robert ?

Comment: You should update the relative paths in both public/index and for you in project/bootstrap/x. In the app.php file in the bootstrap dir it sets the basepath which defines all path bindings in the laravel container itself. Check the Container.php file in the Foundation dir of your framework to see how it expects and handles paths. (including the lookup for the .env file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and

```
php artisan key:generate
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080) post

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the solution. I got: file_get_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LaravelTest/project/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory - as I said before, i think it somehow can't locate the env file.